# How do I "cross" a cell in a table without names

Tags: r, gtable

When I try to adapt the example from the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html) to `gridExtra`, namely

```
g <- tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:3])
g <- gtable_add_grob(g,
        grobs = grobTree(
            segmentsGrob( # diagonal line ul -> lr
                x0 = unit(0,"npc"),
                y0 = unit(1,"npc"),
                x1 = unit(1,"npc"),
                y1 = unit(0,"npc"),
                gp = gpar(lwd = 2.0)),
            segmentsGrob( # diagonal line ll -> ur
                x0 = unit(0,"npc"),
                y0 = unit(0,"npc"),
                x1 = unit(1,"npc"),
                y1 = unit(1,"npc"),
                gp = gpar(lwd = 2.0))),
        t = 3, b = 3, l = 3, r = 3
    )
grid.draw(g)
```

[image: Result of vignette code]

to my dataset, which does not have row names or column names, no cross appears:

```
g <- tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:3], rows=NULL, cols=NULL) # the only line that is changed
g <- gtable_add_grob(g,
        grobs = grobTree(
            segmentsGrob( # diagonal line ul -> lr
                x0 = unit(0,"npc"),
                y0 = unit(1,"npc"),
                x1 = unit(1,"npc"),
                y1 = unit(0,"npc"),
                gp = gpar(lwd = 2.0)),
            segmentsGrob( # diagonal line ll -> ur
                x0 = unit(0,"npc"),
                y0 = unit(0,"npc"),
                x1 = unit(1,"npc"),
                y1 = unit(1,"npc"),
                gp = gpar(lwd = 2.0))),
        t = 3, b = 3, l = 3, r = 3
    )
grid.draw(g)
```

[image: slightly adapted]

I am stuck. Any help?

Comment: Removing the cols and rows somehow messes up the parameters for t,b,l,r.  Try playing around with those.

Comment: I would think it would be `t = 2, b = 2, l = 2, r = 2`, since `t = 2, b = 2, l = 2, r = 3` span the `3 | 1.4` cells, but when I try the first, nothing shows up

Comment: ditto @rawr, suppose a work around is to not have `cols=NULL`( ie keep the headers), and then use `g = g[-1, ]`

Comment: huh, weird, using b = 1.something up to 2.something (something !=0) (ie (b=1.1, or b=2.9)*works* - idu

Comment: good point, `t = 2, b = 2 + 1e-8, l = 2, r = 2` works, that's weird

Comment: @user20650, your workaround with `g[-1,]`does the trick! If you make that an answer, I am happy to accept it.

Comment: @user20650, @rawr: adding a small number to `b` is also a solution to my problem.